# Conectarse a la db postgres en produccion heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

estoy intentando conectar a la base de datos que tengo en produccion(heroku) desde mi pc con pgadmin, se supone que debo pasar las credenciales que me da heroku para crear una coneccion a esa bd todo bien cuando creo un nuevo server con esas credenciales, pero cuando me abre me toma 2500 databases y si intento conectar a una me aparece el siguiente error:

> ```
>     FATAL: permission denied for database "awdo2od23"
>     DETAIL: User does not have CONNECT privilege.
> ```

Las credenciales que se usan son las siguientes:

```
- Host
- Database
- User
- Port
- Password
- URI
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre una solucion para que solo me tome mi db desde heroku, luego de colocar las credenciales en la creacion de tu nuevo server debes ir a la pestaña "Advance" para luego tomar el valor que heroku te da de la "Database" y colocarlo en el campo db restrictions

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> DB restrictions: **nombre de tu database de heroku**

Luego para finalizar le das a guardar y ya estaras conectado.